# variable constructor selection

Tags: haskell, types, constructor

I am writing a haskell program and I'm new to haskell. I have a user defined data type and trying to use it in a function as an argument. In my function implementation I need to distinguish different constructors used to produce the data. What can I do?

```
data myData = C1 Int | C2 String

myFunc :: myData -> Int
myFunc c from constructor C1 = 0
myFunc c from constructor C2 = 1
```

Comment: check `Maybe`, it's a good example.

Comment: You should check out this tutorial for all the basics: http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? (I suppose you want to pattern match on the constructors)

```
myFunc :: myData -> Int
myFunc (C1 _) = 0
myFunc (C2 _) = 1
```